# C# async awaitable clarification?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, async-await, c#-5.0

I've read [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that :

> Await examines that **awaitable** to see if it has **already** completed; if
>   the awaitable has already completed, then the method just continues
>   running (synchronously, just like a regular method).

What ?

Of course it won't be completed   because it hasn't even started !

example :

```
public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{ 
  await DoSomething();
}
```

Here `await` examines the awaitable to see if it has already completed
(according to the article) , but it (DoSomething) **haven't** event started yet ! , so the result will *always* be `false`

It would make sence if the article was to say :

> Await examines that awaitable to see if it has **already** completed
>   within  `x` ms; (timeout)

I probably missing something here..

Comment: You keep saying that the awaitable "hasn't started yet", but that's only an assertion/assumption in your question, not something you can point to in any documentation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Consider this example:

```
public async Task<UserProfile> GetProfileAsync(Guid userId)
{
    // First check the cache
    UserProfile cached;
    if (profileCache.TryGetValue(userId, out cached))
    {
        return cached;
    }

    // Nope, we'll have to ask a web service to load it...
    UserProfile profile = await webService.FetchProfileAsync(userId);
    profileCache[userId] = profile;
    return profile;
}
```

Now imagine calling that within another async method:

```
public async Task<...> DoSomething(Guid userId)
{
    // First get the profile...
    UserProfile profile = await GetProfileAsync(userId);
    // Now do something more useful with it...
}
```

It's *entirely* possible that the task returned by `GetProfileAsync` will already have completed by the time the method returns - because of the cache. Or you could be awaiting something other than the result of an async method, of course.

So no, your claim that the awaitable won't have completed by the time you await it isn't true.

There are other reasons, too. Consider this code:

```
public async Task<...> DoTwoThings()
{
    // Start both tasks...
    var firstTask = DoSomethingAsync();
    var secondTask = DoSomethingElseAsync();

    var firstResult = await firstTask;
    var secondResult = await secondTask;
    // Do something with firstResult and secondResult
}
```

It's possible that the second task will complete before the first one - in which case by the time you *await* the second task, it will have completed and you can just keep going.

Comment: Was microsoft was so frustrated with `Task<..>` syntax that they decided to write this as a sugar syntax ?I mean its just like starting  Tasks and inspecting the Result prop...

Comment: @RoyiNamir: No, it's really not. It's a very long way from that. I suggest you take my async code at https://github.com/jskeet/DemoCode/tree/master/AsyncIntro and try rewriting it without `async`. You'll find it *much* more painful, I promise you. The compiler is doing an awful lot of work to remove boilerplate, error-prone code.

Comment: Jon, In your example you used "_downloading from a webservice_" -- an `IO` operation which probably supports asynchronous methods (e.g. beginXXX)  -- so we don't want to block the thread while IO is in progress. **BUT** what if `DoSomething` would be just a method which calculates long fibonacci numbers ? even if we open a  `Task` , it will waste _another_ thread to do the calculation. and so I ask , does the true benefit is for IO operations ? thank you.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: For a compute-bound task you'd want to create a new task, probably on a thread-pool thread, e.g. with `Task.Run`. There's still a benefit there, in terms of getting back to the UI thread when it's completed.

Answer (score 4):

[await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156528.aspx) can take any `Task` or `Task<T>`, *including completed tasks*.

In your example, the inner `DoSomething()` method (that should rather be named `DoSomethingAsync()`, and its caller `DoSomethingElseAsync()`) returns a `Task` (or a `Task<T>`). That task can be a completed task fetched from somewhere else, the method is not required to start its own task.